# C# bind textedits to an object (Winforms)

Tags: c#, object, data-binding

my question is, how can I bind an object to textedits at runtime?

```
namespace MyProgram
{
   public partial class Form1: DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
   {
   MyPerson person = new MyPerson();
   private void FillTextedit()
   {
      person = util.GetPersonByID(1);
      txePhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "Phone");
   }
....
```

FillTextedit get another person and I want to fill my txePhone with the correct object and! I want to get any changes in txePhone.Text in my class person.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Where is the problem?

Comment: I get an error, that it cannot bind an object two times